# Single Android Thread for Multiple Jobs

Tags: java, android, multithreading, task

I would like to have an application which either loads or saves data through a HTTP request, however the data must interact with the UI thread. Ideally, I would like a single thread to use an IF statement on a message to determine if the request is to "load" or "save".

**What would be the simplest way of doing this with the smallest amount of code?**

Also, do instances of Handlers run on individual threads?

EDIT: This is the code I am using now:

```
Handler doStuff = new Handler(){
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg){
            if(msg.what == 1){
                // Load all the information.
                // Get the ID from sharedPrefs
                SharedPreferences details= getSharedPreferences("details", 0);
                String ID = patDetails.getString("id", "error");
                // Load up the ID from HTTP
                String patInfo = httpInc.getURLContent("info.php?no="+AES.encrypt("387gk3hjbo8sgslksjho87s", ID));
                // Separate all the details
                patientInfo = patInfo.split("~");
            }
            if(msg.what == 2){
                // Save the data
            }
        }
    };
```

Eclipse halts the debugging and displays, "Source not found" for StrictMode.class

I suppose it's because it's using the Main thread to access the internet although it's running in individual threads.

Any idea.

Comment: It would help if you post the code for what you've tried, and any error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Handlers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) do run on individual threads.  Check that link.  You should also check out [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Comment: I have implemented a handler to manage two different messages, but their is an ioexception on the main thread then I execute the HTTP request.

Answer (score 0):

I would propose submitting the jobs as `Runnable` to a single-threaded [`ExecutorService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html):

```
public class SomeClass {
  private ExecutorService execService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

  public void doSomething() {
    final String someUiData = // retrieve data from UI

    execService.submit(new Runnable() {

      @Override
      public void run() {
        // so something time-consuming, which will be executed asynchronously from the UI thread
        // you can also access someUiData here...
      }
    });
  }
}
```

This way, the UI thread will not block whereas you can easily submit a different `Runnable` for different operations and the `ExecutorService` will completely take care of keeping it async.

**Edit:** If you need to interact with the UI, do so before becoming asynchronous and keep the result in final variables.